# Appending Comma Separated Values File (.csv) to Text File (VB.net)

Tags: c#, vb.net

Good day everyone, I am currently working on a simple VB.net app that appends a *Comma Separated Values File (.csv)* file to Text a file or Vice Versa in (VB.net).

The thing is, when the CSV file is appended to a text file it writes this way.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYORi.png)

The output I want to see is something like this.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95ezy.png)

Here is my current code in appending a file to another.

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items

            Dim fileContent As String = File.ReadAllText(item.ToString)

            For Each item2 In ListBox2.Items()

                File.AppendAllText(item2.ToString, fileContent)

            Next
        Next
```

(ListBox1 contains the Source File/the file to be appended to Destination File)

```
 If (open.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        For Each file As String In open.FileNames
            Dim temp As String = ListBox1.Text
            ListBox1.Items.Add(file.ToString)
        Next

    Else
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblMessage.Visible = True
        lblMessage.Text = "** PLEASE CHOOSE FILE TYPE **"
    End If
```

(ListBox2 contains the Destination File/where *Source File* to be appended)

```
If (open.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        For Each file As String In open.FileNames
            Dim temp As String = ListBox2.Text
            ListBox2.Items.Add(file.ToString)
        Next

    Else
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblMessage.Visible = True
        lblMessage.Text = "** PLEASE CHOOSE FILE TYPE **"
    End If
```

Here's exactly an example of an item inside the ListBox1.

[image: Open in Excel]

But when I open the file in notepad it goes like this.

[image: In notepad]

Hoping someone can help.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: A hint: your files obviously do not end with an empty line. So you'll need to append a CRLF (see Environment.NewLine) first and then the content of the file. But, what if the destination file already ends with CRLF? ;)

Comment: What does the data in the files in ListBox1 look like? Commas? Several lines?

Comment: Hi @Mary please see the updates on my question. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how you could have possible gotten the Current Output from the sample data you provided with `File.AppendAllText(item2.ToString, fileContent)` Can you provide the actual code you used.

Answer (score 0):

you just need a simple for loop:

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(inputFile.csv);
string[] data = r.ReadToEnd().split(',');
r.close();
string output = "";
for(int i=0; i<data.length ; ++i){
   if(i%3 == 0 && i != 0){
      output += "\n";
   }
   output += (data[i] + ' '); 
}
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter('output.txt');
   w.WriteLine(output);
w.close();
```

Comment: when I anwser your question is not completed same like now and perhaps it is not true for your new edition

Comment: It seems your answer doesn't answer the question. You are not appending to existing files.

Comment: yeah it is for first edition of his question :))

Comment: ok ok I delete my anwser :/

Comment: I changed my answer right now

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try this one.